# IntegrityError at /cregister/ "Column 'user_customer_id' cannot be null"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Customer(models.Model):
    user_customer  = models.OneToOneField(User)
    customer_name  = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    phone_no       = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    inserted       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True,blank=True)
    created        = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from accounts.models import User
from accounts.forms import RegisterForm
from .forms import CustomerRegistration
from .models import Customer


def CustomerSignupView(request):
    r_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    c_form = CustomerRegistration(request.POST or None)
    context = {
            "r_form":r_form ,
            "c_form":c_form ,
          }
    if r_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
        instance = r_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.is_customer = True
        instance.save()
        c_form.save()
        return redirect("/")
    return render(request,"customerregister.html",context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Customer

class CustomerRegistration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('customer_name','phone_no',)
```

I have two separate forms - RegisterationForm(RF) and CustomerRegistrationForm(CRF).
CRF inherits RF, I want to save two forms in single view i.e.CustomerSignupView.

While submitting the forms Intergrity error pops up, and the data saved is only from RegistrationForm.

How do I save both forms in thier respective table with integrity maintained.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your forms, but it looks as if you have to set the user before you save the customer to the database:

```
if r_form.is_valid() and c_form.is_valid():
    instance = r_form.save(commit=False)
    instance.is_customer = True
    instance.save()
    customer = c_form.save(commit=False)
    customer.user_customer = instance
    customer.save()
    return redirect("/")
```

Comment: I didint tested... but i guess c_form will keep faling because user is one required field at Customer Model... so the c_form maybe need be checked after the user be saved? or maybe after the .save(commit=False) ?

Comment: @DiegoVinícius *but I guess `c_form` will keep failing because user is one required field* - it looks like `c_form` excludes the user field, otherwise the form would be invalid. It would be easier to answer if the Akshay included the forms in the question.

Comment: even if he excludes the user field from form he wont be able to persist it because is required in database... check the error he posted “Column 'user_customer_id' cannot be null”

Comment: @DiegoVinícius My answer above shows how to set `user_customer` to avoid the 'cannot be null' error.

Comment: My doubt is "c_form.is_valid" trigger the error cannot be null? or it can pass and your line 6 can fix the problem... that is my question

Comment: No, the 'cannot be null' error is not coming from `is_valid()`, it is coming from `save()`. It would be good if the OP had included the full traceback, then that would have been clearer.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create a User from accounts.models before creating you Customer, if your r_form is a instance of User your c_form will fail because **user** is required to c_form be valid

```
if r_form.is_valid():
    instance = r_form.save(commit=False)
    instance.is_customer = True
    instance.save()
    if c_form.is_valid():
        customer = c_form.save(commit=False)
        customer.user_customer = instance
        customer.save()
    return redirect("/")
```

**Suggestion**: why you not Inherite User to your Customer since your Customer is once User

```
from accounts.models import User

class Costumer(User):
    ...
```

This way you can setup the Costumer and User in just one form, is easy to acess the data from Costumer.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to split the `r_form.is_valid()` and `c_form.is_valid()` checks. That way you create `instance` even if the `c_form` is invalid. The OP probably wants to create both the customer and user, or not create either.

Comment: Maybe he should put User as null=True so that way he can pass in both checks and do his logic

Comment: The forms are already valid. The error is coming from the `save()`, not the `is_valid()` checks.